# How to implement similar html page scrubber like Arc90's Readability or Instapaper?

Tags: html, parsing

I'm interested to find out how to scrub a html page and present it nicely -- remove all the clutters and reformat the main text into a very readable format -- like http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability or Instapaper.

Is it a simple page parsing and removing elements that are not within

?

Was this discussed somewhere else?

Comment: Their initial release was open source and can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/arc90labs-readability/source/browse/tags/final-releases/1.5.0/js/readability.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/jiminoc/goose/wiki does something like you're asking, source code is openly available along with unit tests

Comment: It looks promising. I would use something like that for my personal project, very useful, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Readability is not a simple parser, it use complex algorithm to retrieve only the required components, if you are a not a guru at programming i would suggest you use their free service highlighted below.

you can request for a developer api from readability (http://www.readability.com/publishers/api)

If you request for the parser it will do exactly what you want to achieve, and that is to extract content from sites. Just remember to give them a good enough reason to allow you to use their API.

A query to their parsing service will look like the following

> https://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser?url={url to be parsed here}&token={your api key here}

The request will return a response like:

> HTTP/1.0 200 OK {
>       "domain": "blog.readability.com", 
>       "author": "Richard Ziade",
>       "url": "http://blog.readability.com/2011/02/step-up-be-heard-readability-ideas/",
>
> ```
> "short_url": "http://rdd.me/kbgr5a1k",
> "title": "Step Up & Be Heard: Readability Ideas", 
> "total_pages": 1, 
> "word_count": 175, 
> "content": "<div>\n  \n<div class=\"entry\">\n\t<p>When we launched Readability [snip] ...</div>\n</div>", 
> "date_published": "2011-02-22 00:00:00", 
> "next_page_id": null, 
> "rendered_pages": 1 }
> ```

For the hard core guys out there, checkout readability nodeJS,ruby and python port from here
http://arrix.blogspot.com/2010/11/server-side-readability-with-nodejs.html

Happy coding

Comment: Thanks -- the motivation is to basically find out how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

If the web page or site in question has good use of semantic elements and structure, you could just use a different CSS stylesheet, which can drastically change the layout and display completely.