# Getting the web page content, similar to Readability as service

Tags: html, parsing, readability

I'm looking for some facility for getting out clean HTML content for different pages (blog articles, magazines etc). The basic idea is how the 'Reader' in iOS Safary works.

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/387572/how-does-safaris-reader-work-and-when-does-it-show-up) answer I can up that iOS Safary uses [Readability](http://www.readability.com) for content parsing. Unfortunatelly the [API](http://www.readability.com/publishers/api) does not include any methods for parsing, instead saving a bookmark and getting it's content, which does not suit me much.

Another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9635303/386751) suggests to use https://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser but it does not work for me.

Any suggestions for similar services?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Tranquility](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tranquility-1/). It is a Firefox Add-on so you can look at the source. You can download the XPI and unpack it. Then look into content/tranquility.js and the related files in content/.